# The Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm: what does len = lps[len - 1] do in the algorithm and what's the consequence of changing it?

Tags: c++, algorithm

**An implementation of KMP algorithm:**

```
std::vector<int> kmpProcess(std::string s) {
     int n = s.size();
     std::vector<int> lps(n, 0);
     for (int i = 1, len = 0; i < n;) {
         if (s[i] == s[len]) {
             lps[i++] = ++len;
         } else if (len) {
             len = lps[len - 1]; // the line I have question with
         } else {
             lps[i++] = 0;
         }
     }
     return lps;
 }
```

I do not fully understand what `len = lps[len - 1]` does. I think it somehow resets `len` so that prefix can be compared with a shorter suffix. What if we change this line to `len--;`? What would be the difference? Will `len--;` even work correctly?

Comment: Why not try it and see? Presumably there's a good reason it does that. I imagine papers discussing the algorithm would indicate what that is.